# What song is playing in Cassie's earbuds during her intro?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x, game-music-identification

Sounds like a Mortal Kombat song, but I can't put my hand on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3 Intro music (Attract mode in arcade). It's also used during credits in MK3, UMK3 and some ports of Trilogy.